# How to login in SMTP lib without enabling less secure apps in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

My problem is simple I want users to log in to their Google account using STMP Lib without having to enable less secure apps for their google account.

Comment: See SASL XOAUTH2. I don't know if anyone ever built support for Python's smtplib, though; you may need to do that yourself.

Comment: in Gmail you have to generate new password for your application and use this password instead of password which you use in web browser.